# Adding items from lists to list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

Lets say i have one list *a* and a list of lists *b*:

```
a = ['1','2','3']
b = [['Hello'],['I'],['am']]
```

How could i go about getting the following output?

```
b = [['Hello','1'],['I','2'],['am','3']]
```

I have tried various things unsuccesfully like the following.

```
for i in a:
    for j in range(b):
        j.append(i[j])
print(b)
```

EDIT:
I was looking for a way to do this, in case the two lists is not of the same length, which the duplicate does not answer. If you look in the comments on the accepted answer, you will fin the solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a list comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
r = [[s[0], n] for (n, s) in zip(a, b)]
```

---

update after comments:

if your lists are not of the same length you can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) and something like

```
from itertools import zip_longest

r = [s if n is None else
     [n] if s is None else
     [s[0], n] for (n, s) in zip_longest(a, b)]
```

Comment: Will this work if lists arent of the same length?

Comment: Another option: `[u + [v] for u, v in zip(b, a)]`

Comment: @briyan What do you want to do with the leftover stuff if the lists aren't the same length?

Comment: Just add nothing to those elements.

Comment: `zip` will stop after the first list is exhausted. but there is [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) where you can add a `fillvalue`.

Comment: Thanks! will accept this.

Comment: @briyan Here's my version modified to handles either list being longer than the other. `[u if v is None else [v] if u is None else u + [v] for u, v in zip_longest(b, a)]`

Comment: @briyan It's a shame that you didn't mention that you need to handle unequal list lengths in your question, and how you want to handle them, since the answers in the question that juanpa.arrivillaga used to close this question don't really show how to do that. If you just use `zip_longest` without including a test like I used then your lists end up having `None` (or some other default value) in them.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, i will update the question when i get home, and point people to your comment. I figured it out with your guys' help - so hopefully others will too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
>>> a = ['1','2','3']
>>> b = [['Hello'],['I'],['am']]
>>> ab = [[b[i][0], a[i]] for i in range(len(a))]
```

Comment: Will this work if lists arent of the same length?

Comment: No, It won't. You will need to modify this if you have lists that are not in same length.